# Why can't put Eigen Map into a class?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I try to put Eigen Map into a definition of a class, but it cannot pass the compiler. The following is the "ex.cc" file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen; using namespace std;

class bc{
  double a[10];
  Map<ArrayXd> b(a, 10);
};

int main(){
  bc x;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
ex.cc:6:19: error: ‘a’ is not a type
ex.cc:6:22: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
ex.cc:6:22: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

I do not know why. I am doing exactly as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) except that I 
put the Map into a class.

Comment: You can't initialize a class member like that. Write a constructor, use braces (`Map<ArrayXd> b{a, 10};`), or do `Map<ArrayXd> b = Map<ArrayXd>(a, 10);`. The latter two requires C++11.

Comment: @T.C. I follow your suggestion. It does not work. But when I tried to use initialization list for the constructor, it works. Thanks